# Responsive carousal that adds li elements on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, date, css-animations

I'm trying to create a sort of sliding carousal that displays the date (A zoomed-in calender view). Where three list elements show on the carousal (yesterday's date, today's date, tomorrow's date). When you click the 'next' button it slides (with transition) to the next date in order, and when you click the 'prev' button it shows the previous date in order.

I set the three list elements to be 33.2% in a 100% container, so I'm not sure where to add the 'next' and 'prev' list elements whenever a button is clicked. It would be simpler if I did it all in pixels because I can then have every added element off canvas side-by-side, but I'm using percentages. Also, because the date numbers vary month by month I have to add the list items through js.

```js
var date = new Date();
 var day  = date.getDate();
 
 $(".yesterday p").text(day - 1);
 $(".today p").text(day);
 $(".tomorrow p").text(day + 1);
```

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.calender{
 width:100%;
 height:500px;
  margin-top:5px;
 border: 1px black solid;
 position:relative;
}

.day{
 width: 33%;
 height:500px;
 border: 1px red solid;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 
}

.day p{
 text-align:center;
 font-size:6em;
}

.next{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 width:25px;
 height:100%;
 background-color:green;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.next:hover{
 background-color:red;
}

.prev{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:25px;
 height:100%;
 background-color:green;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.prev:hover{
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <ul class="calender"> <!-- zoomed in cal -->
  
  <li class="day yesterday"> <p></p> </li>
  <li class="day today"> <p></p> </li>
  <li class="day tomorrow"> <p></p> </li>
  
 
  
 </ul>
  <li class="next"></li>
  <li class="prev"></li>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed the list to inline-block instead of float. I also added all list elements (dates) on page load, instead of adding them one at a time with each click.

```js
 var d = new Date();
 var month = d.getMonth()+1;
 var year = d.getFullYear();
 var day  = d.getDate();
 
 var getDaysInMonth = function(month,year) {  
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
 }

 var count = 0;
    var slide = 33 * (day - 2);

 for (x=0; x < getDaysInMonth(month, year); x++)
 {
  count += 1;
  $(".calender").append("<li class='day "+count+"'><p>"+count+"</p></li>");
  $(".1").css("margin-left","-"+slide+"%");
 }
 
 var next = 0;
 
 $(".next").click(function(){
 
  next  += 1;
  slide += 33;
  $(".1").animate({marginLeft: '-'+slide+'%'}, "fast");
 });
 
 var prev = 0;
 
 $(".prev").click(function(){
  
  if (slide > 0)
  {
   prev  += 1;
   slide -= 33;
   $(".1").animate({marginLeft: '-'+slide+'%'}, "fast");
  }
 });
```

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 overflow-y:hidden;
}

.calender{
 width:100%;
 height:50vh;
 border: 1px #FFF solid;
 margin-top:20px;
 position:relative;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font-family: 'Lato';
 color:#FFF;
}

.day{
 width: 33%;
 height:50vh;
 border: 1px #FFF solid;
 display: inline-block;
 position:relative;
 background-color:#35a541;
}

.day p{
 text-align:center;
 font-size:6em;
}

.next{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 width:25px;
 height:100%;
 background-color:green;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.next:hover{
 background-color:red;
}

.prev{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:25px;
 height:100%;
 background-color:green;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.next:hover{
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
 <script src='code/jquery-1.12.2.min.js'></script>
 <script src="code.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
 <ul class="calender"> <!-- zoomed in cal -->
 
  
 </ul>
  <li class="next"></li>
  <li class="prev"></li>

</body>

</html>
```